# Improve performance of query on view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following query (table has 2.2M records)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [s].[ListingId], [s].[Url]
FROM [SitemapListingsExpired] AS [s]
ORDER BY [s].[ListingId]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=300000,@__p_1=10000
```

That takes about 20 seconds on prod machine and like to make it a bit faster if possible

View

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SitemapListingsExpired]

AS 

SELECT
ListingId,
LOWER('/' + cn.code + '/' + r.Code +'/' + c.UnicodeName +'/')+
dbo.ToUrlFriendly(l.Title) + '-' + CAST(l.ListingID AS VARCHAR(500)) AS Url
    
FROM [dbo].ListingsExpired l
    INNER JOIN Cities c ON l.CityId = c.CityId
    INNER JOIN Regions r ON r.RegionId = c.RegionId
    INNER JOIN Countries cn ON cn.CountryId = r.CountryId
```

Actual Plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkoWk5_m3

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ToUrlFriendly]
(   
    
    @content VARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN LOWER(dbo.UrlEncode(dbo.ReplaceASCII(

trim(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
(cast(TRIM(@content) as varchar(1000)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI)
, '"', '')
, '}', '')
, '{', '')
, ' ', '-')
, '&', '-and-')
, '/', '-')
, '\', '-')
, ',', '-')
, '''', '')
, '', '')
, '#', '-')
, ';;', '-')
, ';', '-')
, '.', '-')
, '’', '-')
, '–', '-')
, '®', '-')
, '--', '-')
, '$', '-')
, '---', '-')
, '--', '-')
))))
```

Comment: Your current rowset pagination is reading 300000 rows only to throw them out the window. Consider using Keyset Pagination instead of paging by rownumber, as this can be much faster. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457 You simply remember which `ListingId` you were up to and begin from there. Also, move that URL function into procedural code in C#/VB (which you are clearly using as this looks like Entity Framework generated)

Comment: @Charlieface I am indeed using EF, I didnt think of moving the url friendly function to the code, I will do that. but the pagination is the built in EF that generates the rownumber, i am not familiar with keyset  pagination

Edit: looked at keyset pagination, will try to implement that, but from query/view perspective, can anything else be improved?

Comment: Read the link and decide if you want it. It's pretty simple to understand, but requires redesigning your application to be able to work with it. You need to first read a bunch of rows sorted by a unique key `SitemapListingsExpired.OrderBy(l => l.ListingId).Take(10000)` remember the top ID and pass it in on the next run `SitemapListingsExpired.Where(l => l.ListingId > prevMaxID).OrderBy(l => l.ListingId).Take(10000)` and so on

Answer (score 1):

That query uses a 300,000 row offset, which is expensive using `OFFSET`/`FETCH`.  If you're reading that deep into the resultset, don't use EF's `Skip`.  Either use [keyset pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457), or simply eliminate the paging by turning off change tracking on the query, enumerate the results to stream all the rows you need.

For example, for keyset pagination, you need to first read a bunch of rows sorted by a unique key

```cs
SitemapListingsExpired
  .OrderBy(l => l.ListingId)
  .Take(10000)
```

Then remember the top ID and pass it in on the next run

```cs
SitemapListingsExpired
  .Where(l => l.ListingId > prevMaxID)
  .OrderBy(l => l.ListingId)
  .Take(10000)
```

and so on

Comment: Good point.  Updated answer.